# Is there a resolution on IIS for this SEO canonical issue?

Tags: seo, canonical-link

I have a site running on IIS that I have a *canonical issue* with.

The error is:

> The page with URL "http://example.org/images/join_forum.gif" can also be accessed by using URL "https://example.org/images/join_forum.gif".
>
> Search engines identify unique pages by using URLs.  When a single page can be accessed by using any one of multiple URLs, a search engine assumes that there are multiple unique pages. Use a single URL to reference a page to prevent dilution of page relevance. You can prevent dilution by following a standard URL format.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

If the only difference is `http` vs `https` then don't worry about it. Search engines are smart enough to know they are the same file. And especially so for images.

Comment: what about http://site.com and http://www.site.com
this is anothe rpain in my but...

Comment: Yes, in that case try and make sure you always point to the same domain. The best way is a 301 redirect from one version of the domain to the other (search Stack Overflow or Google, you'll find how to do it), but you can also set a preferred domain in Google webmaster tools - http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/

Answer (score -4):

If you're experiencing SEO canonical issues on a website hosted on IIS (Internet Information Services), there are several potential solutions to address these problems. Canonicalization issues typically arise when search engines encounter multiple URLs that represent the same or very similar content. Here are some steps you can take to resolve SEO canonicalization issues on IIS:

Set Preferred Domain:
Choose a preferred domain (e.g., [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) or example.com) and ensure that all internal and external links consistently point to the preferred version. You can set the preferred domain using canonical tags in your HTML or by configuring your IIS server to redirect to the preferred version.

Redirect Non-Preferred Versions:
Use 301 redirects to ensure that all non-preferred versions of your URLs (e.g., http://example.com) redirect to the preferred version (e.g., http://www.example.com). This helps consolidate link equity and prevents search engines from indexing duplicate content.

Canonical Tags:
Implement canonical tags in the HTML head of your web pages. These tags indicate the preferred version of a page and can help search engines understand the canonical URL. For example:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/page" />
```

URL Rewrite Module:
Use the URL Rewrite module in IIS to create rules that enforce canonical URLs. This allows you to set up redirections and modify URLs based on specific conditions. Ensure that the module is installed and configured correctly.

Remove Trailing Slashes:
Decide on a consistent URL structure (with or without trailing slashes) and ensure that all internal and external links follow this structure. You can use URL rewriting to enforce a consistent structure.

Check for Parameter Variations:
If your URLs include parameters, ensure that they don't create multiple versions of the same content. Use the canonical tag or parameter handling in Google Search Console to inform search engines about parameter variations.

Check for Case Sensitivity:
URLs on IIS are case-insensitive by default, but if you have manually configured them in a case-sensitive manner, it can lead to canonicalization issues. Ensure that URLs are consistently represented in a case-insensitive manner.

Use HTTPS:
If your website is accessible over both HTTP and HTTPS, ensure that you have implemented proper redirects to the secure (HTTPS) version of your site. This helps prevent duplicate content issues.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This was a copy-paste from ChatGPT before the edit, and it's a different copy-paste from ChatGPT after the edit. This isn't an improvmenet